# colocar imagen mediante after (css) que el footer quede encima

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

¿Cómo hago para colocar una imagen de tal forma que el footer quede encima de la imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código css que tengo

```
body::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: url(../img/sheet_b.png) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con z-index:

> El valor de z-index indica la posición de profundidad (capa) de u objeto en la página. Los elementos con valores positivos son apilados encima de uno con valores negativos, menores, o no especificados. Dos objetos con el mismo z-index son organizados dependiendo de la colocación de sus etiquietas. Un valor negativo posiciona el objeto debajo de otro que no lo tenga definido. Para remover el efecto, se retira o se cambia el parametro a null.
>
> Nota: La propiedad z-index solo aplica a elementos que tengan la
>   propiedad position en absolute o relative.

fragmento obtenido de [cristalab](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/superposicion-de-objetos-de-html-overlapping-con-css-c184l/).

Aquí esta un ejemplo funcionando, espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

```css
.footer{
  z-index:1;
  background-color: blue;
}

.imagen{
  z-index:-1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -70px;
}
```

```html
<img class="imagen" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/02/09/43/apple-1302430_960_720.jpg">

<div class="footer">
  <h1>Este es el footer<h1><br>
</div>
```